# Joomla 3.0 creating dummy menu item

Tags: joomla

This seems so elementary, but I just don't exactly know how to even look for the answer.

I'm using Joomla 3.0 with the Protostar template, and I'm trying to create a menu item (using the horizontal nav-pills style) which will, when clicked, cause only the submenu items to display, as opposed to refreshing the page THEN showing a submenu.  As it is now, I can't figure out how to create the top menu item in a way that it doesn't have its own link associated with it.

For example, my top three menu items are "Home", "Orders", "Staff".  If I click Staff, I don't want it to take me to any other page, just show me a submenu of the staff members.  How can I do this?

I've tried using a "menu header" menu item type, but it doesn't even create it as a link, just plain text -- not to mention the CSS is all wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Menu item type -> System Links -> Text Separator. Then create other menu items as children of this element.

Comment: Tried that but I get the same result as with a menu header -- it's not a hyperlink so clicking on it has no effect.  Plus the styling is different, but that's easier to deal with.

Comment: @trpt4him FYI, for me there's a hyperlink but the styling is different.

Comment: @trpt4him in your question you definetely tell us that you **don't need** link in level-1 menu parent item. This part- **how to create the top menu item in a way that it doesn't have its own link** - now you tell us about opposite things. So, you need to explain us better what do you exactly need.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to define a css class and use this with your menu item!

1. Open your menu item in Joomla.
2. Select "Link type" out of the three tabs (Details, Link Type, Module Assignment).
3. Give the field "Link CSS Style" a css style `not-active`. Just write this (without the quotes or a dot from the css.
4. Go to your templates css-styles: ("Extensions > Template manager. Select your template (not on the left side, but on the right (in the column "Template")).
5. Insert this css class to your templates main css file:

```css
    .not-active {
       pointer-events: none;
       cursor: default;
    }
```

That's all. It works so fine! Regardless which type of menu item you defined.

Answer (score 1):

If the "Text Separator" type is not working, then make it an "External URL" and have it point to "#" (without the quotes).

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

External URL (point to #) is listed under System Links, not Weblinks, where one might look for it.