# Joomla! 3 menu drop-down behavior without showing new article possible?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.2

The Joomla! 3 administrative console in my installed version (Joomla! 3.1.5 Stable) plus at least a Joomla! demo web site showcase menus that don't switch to an article if you press them, but present only the drop-down menu at first. The rendered article (i.e. the content below the menu) only changes once a menu-item is selected/clicked.

For instance, visit [demo.joomla.org](http://demo.joomla.org/). The content below the menu reads "Joomla! is a free, open source content management system ..." Now if you press e.g. "Joomla!" inside the menu, a drop-down list appears, but the cited text does not change yet. Only if you press a particular menu item it changes (currently e.g. to "Joomla! 2.5.16 Released ...").

I would like to accomplish the same behavior in a Joomla! 3-powered web site but haven't yet been able to do so. On my site (sorry, not yet available to the public) clicking a menu of this kind brings up the article, and so far I have found no way to prevent that. I'm referring to articles because my menus are of type "Single Article". I've looked at other menu item types too but they did not seem to offer a solution either.

So can the behavior the demo site's menus be accomplished (without installing further extensions), and if so how? After all, the demos are surely hosted on Jooma! servers :) Perhaps this is a matter of choosing an appropriate template? But then, the solution does not seem obvious and googling reveals different opinions as to whether this is/was possible at all.

**UPDATE** The following is a depiction of what I get when changing the menu item type for "Open Source" from "Articles | Single Article" to "System Links | Text Separator": it now looks odd and no longer seems to function as a menu (no drop-down effect). In the HTML source the CSS classes assigned to the three menu items are "item-*x* current active", "item-*y* divider parent", and "item-*z* parent" respectively. (Why isn't "Open Source" marked active?)

[image]

**UPDATE** I am using the `protostar` template (marked as `Default` for `Site` under `Extensions` | `Type Manager`).

Comment: Please rephrase or add a few screenshots, I can't figure out what you mean by "don't switch to an article...", give us the url / exact description of where the issue is located.

Comment: Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: much clearer, hope I got it right.

Comment: same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395656/joomla-3-0-creating-dummy-menu-item).

Answer (score 2):

Create the top-level menus as System - Separator; this means they have no link attached, but only serve the purpose of organizing (sub)menu links.

Then when you click them, based on the setup of your menu module, they will show the sub-items. Beware, the most common behaviour is not to wait until clicked, but simply show the submenu items when hovered (when you bring the mouse over them).  But the event they respond to depends on the module (mod_menu), its template override, and other scripts your template may load.

**Update:**

If you're using **mod_menu**, in the module list it will be listed as **Menu**; if you were using another menu module, I guess you would remember installing it :-)

I am not a protostar / twitter bootstrap fan so I can't help you much on it, but dropdown menus are definitely supported, I just tried putting the menu in the position `navigation`, with

```
"Menu Class Suffix" = " nav-pills nav-dropdown"
```

and it worked correctly with dropdowns on hover. As per having dropdowns on click instead of hover, look at [this guide](http://learn.theartofjoomla.com/building-sites/a-guide-to-joomla-3-protostar-template.html)

Comment: Thx, but when I try that the top-level menu (item) concerned no longer seems to function (see screenshot in edited question). I've meanwhile also noted that @trpt4him seems to run into the same problem over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395656/joomla-3-0-creating-dummy-menu-item).

Comment: Possibly your menu doesn't take separators into consideration; but that's a limitation of the menu module you are using, Joomla native mod_menu supports it.  I think we need more info here, what template and what menu module are you using?

Comment: FWIK I am using the `protostar` template (see last edit; did not change from defaults; menu does not override default). How can I find out about the module menu? When I search for `mod_menu` in `Extensions` | `Module Manager`, nothing shows up. My menu does not list `mod_menu` in its `Module Assignment for this Menu Item` either (at least not under this name).

Comment: Nops, don't remember installing another menu :) I'm working with a German version, so maybe this is why the name is not "Menu". Is there another way to find out whether `mod_menu` is in use? I choose `Protostar` | `Navigation [position-1]` as position of for item in `Extension` | `Module Manager` that (FWIK) corresponds to my menu uses position. It's then displayed as `position-1`, which may or may not be the same thing. Don't know how to set `Menu Class Suffix`, though, and will digest linked guide next ... BTW, what would you recommend over protostar/twitter bootstrap (to a novice like me)?

Comment: All bootstraps require some coding, be it foundation/siege engine, twitter bootstrap, html5 boilerplate or some others.  If you want a no-coding solution, you need one of the larger (and slower) commercial templates from yootheme, rockettheme, etc.; but then, if you need tweaking, coding will be harder. There is no "one size fits all" that I know of

Comment: You will find Menu Class Suffix in the advanced tab of the menu module.

Comment: Ah, got one step further: The "Advanced Options" of the menu module sits below (not next to) its "Options" tab in my version of Joomla! ...